# How to limit only one user to Edit view MVC 5 .Net at one time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm making a web app with MVC 5 .Net. I want to limit only one user to edit a view at a time. For example user A access to ..../Edit/5.
When user B try to access to some form (.../Edit/5) while user A is still editing i want to show some message like "Other user is editing. Please try again later". On my edit views i have created an auto save feature which saves every 30 sec. So user B cant access to edit form while user A is still editing.(user B need to stay on the same site). I am thinking with something like adding new column in database but i'm thinking what if user A just close browser while still on editing page. The field in database will still be the same so no one else can edit this view.
I hope that you understand my problem i can help me.

Comment: You can handle this is through optimistic concurrency. Let user B open it, but if user A as saved it in the meantime, you can display an message when user B attempts to save it letting them know that's its been edited since they opened it.

Comment: One way is to maintain an application wide static list of Ids of items, which are currently being edited and check if the Id belongs to that list then give user the message you mentioned. When user saves the item or autosave is triggered remove the item from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by creating new table where i keep user id, id from item that is editing and time when is locked. If view is locked less than 30min if someone else try to access i show message but if is more tan 30 min user can edit. also i created JavaScript function  window.onbeforeunload where i unlock view. Also authorize admin to unlock view on button click

Answer (score 0):

You can add one field to your table like "LOCK" and when any user click on edit you change this field to 1 and check for edit if lock == 0 go to view else type error and when user click on save change the lock value to 0

Comment: This does not address the last part of OP's question - it fails if user A starts editing and then closes the browser without saving. The lock remain on and now prevents it from ever being edited again.

Comment: Bro you can add lock field to index view and if any articles was open show the lock image side it like joomla and wordpress and ect
if user click on lock your code unlock this article
i think it's best way because if you do this with time you will have any problems

Comment: Your not understanding the issue! User A edits it, the flag is set to `1`. If user a then abandons it without saving the flag remains set - no one else can ever edit because it has not been reset back to `0`

Comment: My engilish is not very well
if one user click on edit you set lock to 1, ok?
if click on save you change lock to 0 and save article if lock == 1 else show error that this article opened by another user,
if user click on cancel you change lock to 0
if user close the window you have 2 solution
1. you prevent to close window with jquery
2. you set Lock field to Index view that if article lock was 1 show lock's image when user click on Article's lock button change it to 0 again

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Timestamp` to control concurrency :

```
   [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

More details [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)